# How to find size of RAM cache use for ramfs, tmpfs

Tags: linux, memory, tmpfs

I'm wondering if there is any way to specify the size of RAM cache used to store `ramfs`, `tmpfs`?

When I look at `/proc/`, I can't find anything about `ramfs` size.

Comment: did you checked #cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: I already check /proc/meminfo and /proc/vmstat but there are no field about ramfs.

Comment: `ramfs` and `tmpfs` dynamically use/acquire RAM based on need.  They do not have a fixed or hard allocation of RAMemory.  Hence there is no way to specify any allocation size like `ramdisk` has.

Comment: You can simply use `df` or `du`, have a look to my answer below.

Comment: A good talk about ramdisk(initrd), vs ramfs(initramfs), vs tmpfs and their various behavior in terms of memory allocation and usage can be found at the following article written by the guys from the Tin Hat and Tor-ramdisk projects: http://opensource.dyc.edu/ramdisk-vs-ramfs

Answer (score 8):

From http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt:

> Further on you can check the actual RAM+swap use of a tmpfs instance
>   with df(1) and du(1).

So simply use `df` or `du` (you can also use them for ramfs):

```
$ df | grep tmpfs
tmpfs             205032      1136    203896   1% /run
```

so **1136 KB** is in use.

```
$ sudo du -s /run
[sudo] password for jaume: 
1416    /run
```

so **1416 KB** is in use.

Thats's interesting... `df` and `du` report different sizes. What is happening here and which one is right?

`/run` has a subfolder called `/run/shm`, which is itself a separate tmpfs filesytem (although shown as `none`):

```
$ df | grep run
tmpfs             205032      1136    203896   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              512572       280    512292   1% /run/shm
```

Adding both amounts you get the size reported by `du`:

```
$ expr 1136 + 280
1416
```

So the whole story is that 2 tmpfs filesystems use 1416 KB.

(Here's [another reason](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-why-command-df-and-du-reports-different-output.html) why `du` and `df` outputs may differ.)

Comment: `tmpfs` will be backed by swap in case of running low on RAM. Is there some simple way to figure out how much RAM / swap is used by tmpfs?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Not that I know of, but it's possible there's indeed a simple way, you may want to ask a new question.